# create a category filter with vuejs method

Tags: vue.js, categories

I have the following code I am trying to use a function called categorize to filter all of the templates into categories. Each object has a category array. everytime they click on category button a category word is pushed into the selected categories array. if the a template has an category that is in the selected categories array I want to display it. It doesnt work in its current state any ideas?

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 visible-lg-block hidden-md" id="SearchTemplatesLargeContainer">
        <form role="form" role="form" onsubmit="return false">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="searchBar">Search</label>
                <input v-model="searchQuery" type="text" placeholder="Search Tempates" id="searchBar" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Sort By</label>
                <select v-model="sortBy" class="form-control">
          <option value="renderTime">Render Time</option>
          <option value="az">A-Z</option>
          <option value="dateAdded">Newest</option>
        </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Categories</h5>
                <div v-for="category in categories" :class="category + 'Button'" v-on:click.prevent="selectCategory(category)" class="btn btn-default categoryButton">
                    {{category}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--end lg template menu col-lg-3-->

    <!--search templates modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="searchTemplatesModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Search Templates</h2>
                    <!--end .modal-title-->
                </div>
                <!--end modal-header-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Search</label>
                            <input v-model="searchQuery" type="text" placeholder="Search Tempates" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <!--.end searchQuery-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Sort By</label>
                            <select v-model="sortBy" class="form-control">
                                <option value="renderTime">Render Time</option>
                                <option value="az">A-Z</option>
                                <option value="dateAdded">Newest</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <!--end sortBy-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h5>Categories</h5>
                            <div v-for="category in categories" :class="category + 'Button'" v-on:click.prevent="selectCategory(category)" class="btn btn-default categoryButton">
                                {{category}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end categorys-->
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!--end .modal-body-->

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Search</button>
                </div>
                <!--end .modal-footer-->
            </div>
            <!--end .modal-content-->
        </div>
        <!--end .modal-dialog-->
    </div>
     <!-- end search templates modal-->
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="mainHeading">Creative Engine Templates</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div v-cloak v-bind:key="template.itemId + '_' + index" v-for="(template, index) in searchResults" class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <video muted :src="'mysource/'+template.itemId+'/'+template.thumbName+'.mp4'" controls preload="none" controlsList="nodownload nofullscreen" :poster="'mysource/'+template.itemId+'/'+template.thumbName+'.jpg'" loop="loop"></video>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <p class="card-title">{{template.itemName}}</p>
                        <!--end card-title-->
                        <p v-show="displayCount==0" class="card-text">Please create a display to customize</p>
                        <!--end user has no display card-text-->
                        <p v-show="displayCount>0" class="card-text">Custom Text, Custom Colors, Upload Logo</p>
                        <!--end user has display card text-->
                        <p class="card-text">{{template.renderTime}} minutes</p>
                        <a href="#" v-show="loggedIn==true && displayCount>0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                        <!--logged in and has display button-->
                        <a href="#" v-show="loggedIn==false" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled>Customize</a>
                        <!--not logged in button-->
                        <a href="profile.php?showAddDisplayForm=1" v-show="loggedIn==true && displayCount==0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create A Display</a>
                    </div>
                    <!--end card-body-->
                </div>
                <!--end card-->
            </div>
            <!-- end col-md-4-->
        </div>
        <!--end row-->
    </div>
    <!--end col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12-->
</div>
<!--end templates app-->

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#templates',
  data: {
    loggedIn: false,
    displayCount:'36',
    searchQuery:'',
    templateArray: [{"id":"7","itemId":"17520","itemName":"Arrow Bounce","thumbName":"ARROWBOUNCE","dateAdded":"2016-05-20 16:33:42","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/ArrowBounce-Scott\/arrowBounce.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":["LensFlare"]},{"id":"11","itemId":"38752","itemName":"Jitter Zoom Flash","thumbName":"JITTERZOOMFLASH","dateAdded":"2016-05-23 13:49:03","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/JitterZoomFlash-Scott\/JitterZoomFlash.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":["Sports"],"keywordArray":["Sparkles","Snow"]},{"id":"12","itemId":"12737","itemName":"Cloth Drop","thumbName":"CLOTHDROP","dateAdded":"2016-05-23 14:11:42","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/ClothDrop-Scott\/cloth drop.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"15","itemId":"73076","itemName":"Colorful Trans","thumbName":"COLORFULIMAGETRANS","dateAdded":"2016-05-27 10:16:56","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/ColorfulImageTrans-Scott\/ColorfulImageTrans.aep","stillImageLocation":"12.90","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":["Sparkles","Water"]},{"id":"16","itemId":"18488","itemName":"Convex &frac12; Circle","thumbName":"CONVEXHALFCIRCLE","dateAdded":"2016-05-27 10:38:20","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/convexHalfCircle-Scott\/convex half circle.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"17","itemId":"67039","itemName":"Flag Swap","thumbName":"FLAGBACKSWAP","dateAdded":"2016-06-01 15:34:22","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/FlagBackSwap-Scott\/FlagBackSwap.aep","stillImageLocation":"5.83","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"31","itemId":"70006","itemName":"Flag Raise","thumbName":"FLAGRAISE","dateAdded":"2016-06-03 11:13:37","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/FlagRaise-Scott\/flag.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"32","itemId":"58759","itemName":"Logo Dust Poof","thumbName":"LOGODUSTPOOF","dateAdded":"2016-06-03 11:25:34","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/LogoDustPoof-Scott\/LogoDustPoof.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.23","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"33","itemId":"58967","itemName":"Flag Wave (Loop)","thumbName":"FLAGWAVE","dateAdded":"2016-06-03 11:35:49","renderTime":"75","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/FlagWave-Scott\/FlagWave.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"34","itemId":"65288","itemName":"Logo Splash One","thumbName":"LOGOSPLASHONE","dateAdded":"2016-06-03 15:34:19","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/LogoSplashOne-Scott\/LogoSplashOne.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.70","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"35","itemId":"91246","itemName":"Metal Sparks","thumbName":"METALSPARKS","dateAdded":"2016-06-06 10:58:29","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/MetalSparks-Scott\/MetalSparks.aep","stillImageLocation":"4.63","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"36","itemId":"57489","itemName":"Middle Stripe","thumbName":"MIDDLESTRIPEABA","dateAdded":"2016-06-06 12:25:41","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/MiddleStripe-Scott\/middleStripeABA.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.80","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"37","itemId":"38402","itemName":"Water One","thumbName":"WATERONE","dateAdded":"2016-06-07 09:10:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/waterOne-Scott\/waterOne.aep","stillImageLocation":"8.83","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"39","itemId":"81031","itemName":"Oval Text Flip","thumbName":"OVALTEXTFLIP","dateAdded":"2016-05-07 09:10:32","renderTime":"150","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/OvalTextFlip-Scott\/OvalTextFlip.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"40","itemId":"55143","itemName":"Close Up Text","thumbName":"CLOSEUPTEXT","dateAdded":"2016-07-05 09:10:32","renderTime":"85","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/CloseUpText-Scott\/CloseUpText\/CloseUpText.aep","stillImageLocation":"9.03","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"41","itemId":"54335","itemName":"Electric Text Spin","thumbName":"ELECTRICTEXTSPIN","dateAdded":"2016-07-13 09:10:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/ElectricTextSpin-Scott\/ElectricTextSpin\/ElectricTextSpin.aep","stillImageLocation":"1.47","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"42","itemId":"23761","itemName":"Digital Glitch","thumbName":"DIGITALGLITCH","dateAdded":"2016-09-19 09:10:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/DigitalGlitch-Scott\/DigitalGlitch.aep","stillImageLocation":"3.43","categoryArray":["Retail"],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"43","itemId":"56465","itemName":"Takeover","thumbName":"TAKEOVER","dateAdded":"2016-09-30 14:10:32","renderTime":"80","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/TakeOver-Scott\/TakeoverProject\/takeoverproject.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"44","itemId":"17127","itemName":"Fire One","thumbName":"FIREONE","dateAdded":"2016-11-04 14:10:32","renderTime":"25","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/FireOne-Scott\/FireOne.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"53","itemId":"61617","itemName":"City Spin","thumbName":"CITYSPIN","dateAdded":"2016-11-09 14:17:15","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/CitySpin-Scott\/cityspin.aep","stillImageLocation":"8.933","categoryArray":["Church"],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"56","itemId":"15528","itemName":"Magic Colors","thumbName":"MAGICCOLORS","dateAdded":"2016-11-10 13:10:26","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/MagicColors-Scott\/MagicColors.aep","stillImageLocation":"3.966","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"61","itemId":"59239","itemName":"Quick and Simple","thumbName":"QUICKNSIMPLE","dateAdded":"2016-11-14 11:42:09","renderTime":"15","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/QuickNSimple-Scott\/QuickNSimple.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.033","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"62","itemId":"82460","itemName":"Fast Blast","thumbName":"FASTBLAST","dateAdded":"2016-11-22 10:24:48","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/FastBlast-Scott\/FastBlast.aep","stillImageLocation":"9.666","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"63","itemId":"83530","itemName":"Tunnel Spin","thumbName":"TUNNELSPIN","dateAdded":"2016-12-02 13:09:06","renderTime":"20","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/tunnelSpin-Scott\/tunnelSpin.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.9","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"64","itemId":"94148","itemName":"Sparkle Splash","thumbName":"SPARKLESPLASH","dateAdded":"2016-12-20 11:23:26","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/SparkleSplash-Scott\/SparkleSplash.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.1","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"69","itemId":"98640","itemName":"Gold Bling","thumbName":"GOLDBLING","dateAdded":"2017-01-10 08:16:41","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/GoldBling-Joe\/GoldBling.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"72","itemId":"94169","itemName":"Top Racer","thumbName":"TOPRACER","dateAdded":"2017-02-15 09:46:14","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/TopRacer-Scott\/TopRacer.aep","stillImageLocation":"7.833","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"73","itemId":"55871","itemName":"Desert Sand","thumbName":"DESERTSAND","dateAdded":"2017-02-15 14:04:49","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/DesertSand-Scott\/DesertSand.aep","stillImageLocation":"10.46","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"76","itemId":"18897","itemName":"Electric Storm","thumbName":"ELECTRICSTORM","dateAdded":"2017-02-23 12:43:08","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/ElectricStorm-Scott\/ElectricStorm.aep","stillImageLocation":"4.333","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"78","itemId":"24052","itemName":"Court Smash","thumbName":"COURTSMASH","dateAdded":"2016-06-03 12:03:48","renderTime":"90","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/CourtSmash-Scott\/CourtSmash.aep","stillImageLocation":"5.933","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"81","itemId":"43553","itemName":"Tile Flip","thumbName":"TILEFLIP","dateAdded":"2017-04-25 16:40:41","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/TileFlip-Chris\/TileFlip_Final\/TileFlip_Final.aep","stillImageLocation":"5","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"88","itemId":"94677","itemName":"NEON LIGHTS","thumbName":"NEONLIGHTS","dateAdded":"2017-04-28 10:06:23","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/NEONLIGHTS-Joe\/NeonLights.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.53","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"89","itemId":"64305","itemName":"Engine (Loop)","thumbName":"ENGINE","dateAdded":"2017-05-15 11:37:07","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/Engine-Scott\/Engine.aep","stillImageLocation":"4.67","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"90","itemId":"11287","itemName":"Energy Core","thumbName":"ENERGYCORE","dateAdded":"2017-05-22 13:08:40","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/EnergyCore-Scott\/EnergyCore.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.73","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"91","itemId":"48745","itemName":"Football Helmet","thumbName":"FOOTBALLHELMET","dateAdded":"2017-07-03 16:09:42","renderTime":"120","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/FootballHelmet-Scott\/FootballHelmet.aep","stillImageLocation":"7","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"92","itemId":"85515","itemName":"Light Shine","thumbName":"LIGHTSHINE","dateAdded":"2017-08-18 14:09:50","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/LightShine-Scott\/LightShine.aep","stillImageLocation":"2","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"93","itemId":"61876","itemName":"Baseball Dirt","thumbName":"BASEBALLDIRT","dateAdded":"2017-08-31 10:31:22","renderTime":"40","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/BaseballDirt-Scott\/BaseballDirt.aep","stillImageLocation":"7.27","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"94","itemId":"48066","itemName":"Spooky","thumbName":"SPOOKY","dateAdded":"2017-09-01 13:58:36","renderTime":"15","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/Spooky-Jake\/Spooky.aep","stillImageLocation":"2","categoryArray":["Sports"],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"95","itemId":"33584","itemName":"Get Loud","thumbName":"GETLOUD","dateAdded":"2017-09-07 11:58:02","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/GetLoud-Scott\/GetLoud.aep","stillImageLocation":"1.77","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"96","itemId":"21713","itemName":"STAR BURST","thumbName":"STARBURST","dateAdded":"2017-10-19 18:20:29","renderTime":"15","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/StarBurst-Joe\/StarBurst.aep","stillImageLocation":"0","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"97","itemId":"76554","itemName":"Magic Twirl","thumbName":"MAGICFINAL","dateAdded":"2017-10-26 11:19:52","renderTime":"20","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/Magic-Lillie\/Magic.aep","stillImageLocation":"825","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"98","itemId":"64452","itemName":"Sports Car","thumbName":"SPORTSCAR","dateAdded":"2017-10-27 10:26:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/SportsCar-Scott\/SportsCar.aep","stillImageLocation":"14.77","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"99","itemId":"15074","itemName":"Ice Logo","thumbName":"ICELOGO","dateAdded":"2017-11-01 11:53:48","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/IceLogo-Scott\/IceLogo.aep","stillImageLocation":"9.33","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":["LensFlare"]},{"id":"100","itemId":"95033","itemName":"Hot Air Balloon","thumbName":"BALLOON","dateAdded":"2017-11-02 08:10:22","renderTime":"10","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/Balloon-Lillie\/Balloon.aep","stillImageLocation":"567","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"243","itemId":"f0adeb21cfbfc7e1894debeef4cc6e22","itemName":"testingCrap","thumbName":"TESTINGCRAP","dateAdded":"2018-10-08 18:06:48","renderTime":"4","tested":"0","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/uploads\/testLocation","stillImageLocation":"0.13","categoryArray":["Sports","Holiday"],"keywordArray":["LensFlare"]}],
    filteredTemplateArray: [],
    selectedCategories: [],
    keywords: ["LensFlare","Snow","Water","Sparkles","Sky","Plants"],
    selectedKeywords: [],
    sortBy: ''
  },
  created: function(){
    this.filteredTemplateArray=this.templateArray;
 },
  computed: {
      searchResults: function(){
          return this.filteredTemplateArray.filter((template)=>{
            return template.itemName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase());
          })
      }

  },
    methods: {
    selectCategory: function(category) {
      var categoryButton = $('.' + category + 'Button');
      categoryButton.toggleClass('categoryButtonSelected');
      if(this.selectedCategories.includes(category)){
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.selectedCategories.length; i++) {
          if(this.selectedCategories[i] != category) {
            array.push(this.selectedCategories[i]);
          }
        }
        this.selectedCategories = array;
      } else {
        this.selectedCategories.push(category);
      }
        this.categorize();
    },
                  categorize: function(){
    return this.filteredTemplateArray.filter((template)=>{
        return template.categoryArray.inArray(this.selectedCategories);
    })
    }
}
});
<script>
```

Comment: I don't know where you are getting categories from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a watcher that watches selectedCategories and when it changes run a method that filters out the duplicates and sets filtered categories back to the original array when the selectedCategories.length==0. This creates a category filter that counts up. for instance if sports and holidays are checked it will show only all items in sports and all items in holidays which seems to work better than counting down or showing the ones that only exist in both. I use app instead of this as its the variable i called my vue instance and because when you get deep into a function this does not always mean the app.

```
    watch: {
      selectedCategories(){
          this.categoryFilter();
      },
          sortBy(){
              this.sortTemplatesBy();
          }
    },
  methods: {
            sortTemplatesBy: function(){ 
      if(this.sortBy == "az") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          if(a.itemName > b.itemName) {
            return 1;
          }
          if(a.itemName < b.itemName) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      if(this.sortBy == "dateAdded") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          if(a.dateAdded < b.dateAdded) {
            return 1;
          }
          if(a.dateAdded > b.dateAdded) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      if(this.sortBy == "renderTime") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          return parseInt(a.renderTime) - parseInt(b.renderTime);
        });
      }
    },
      categoryFilter: function(){
          if(app.selectedCategories.length!=0){
          app.filteredTemplateArray=[];
          var templateArray = app.templateArray;
          for(i=0; i<app.selectedCategories.length; i++){
              var filtered=templateArray.filter(function(template){
                  var currentCategory=app.selectedCategories[i];
                  console.log("this is current category"+currentCategory+"end currentCategory");
                  var returnValue=template.categoryArray.includes(currentCategory);
                  console.log("this is i"+i+"end i");
                  console.log("this is return value"+returnValue+"end return value");
                  return returnValue;
              });
              console.log(filtered);
              app.filteredTemplateArray=app.filteredTemplateArray.concat(filtered);

      }
          var uniqueArray=[];
          var allResultsArray=app.filteredTemplateArray;
          for(j=0; j<allResultsArray.length; j++){
              if(uniqueArray.indexOf(allResultsArray[j]) == -1){
                  uniqueArray.push(allResultsArray[j])
              }
          }
          app.filteredTemplateArray=uniqueArray;
      } else {app.filteredTemplateArray=app.templateArray;}
          this.sortTemplatesBy();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure I understand the question, but.
Try creating a method for checking if a category is in the `selectedCategories` array

```
methods: {    
  isInSelectedCategories(category) {
    return this.selectedCategories.includes(category)
  }
  ...
}
```

In your template, you can do this check like so:

> `v-if="isInSelectedCategories(template.category)"`

```
<!-- end search templates modal-->
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="mainHeading">Creative Engine Templates</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div v-cloak v-bind:key="template.itemId + '_' + index" v-for="(template, index) in searchResults" v-if="isInSelectedCategories(template.category)" class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <video muted :src="'mysource/'+template.itemId+'/'+template.thumbName+'.mp4'" controls preload="none" controlsList="nodownload nofullscreen" :poster="'mysource/'+template.itemId+'/'+template.thumbName+'.jpg'" loop="loop"></video>
                <div class="card-body">

                    <p class="card-title">{{template.itemName}}</p>
                    <!--end card-title-->
                    <p v-show="displayCount==0" class="card-text">Please create a display to customize</p>
                    <!--end user has no display card-text-->
                    <p v-show="displayCount>0" class="card-text">Custom Text, Custom Colors, Upload Logo</p>
                    <!--end user has display card text-->
                    <p class="card-text">{{template.renderTime}} minutes</p>
                    <a href="#" v-show="loggedIn==true && displayCount>0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                    <!--logged in and has display button-->
                    <a href="#" v-show="loggedIn==false" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled>Customize</a>
                    <!--not logged in button-->
                    <a href="profile.php?showAddDisplayForm=1" v-show="loggedIn==true && displayCount==0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create A Display</a>
                </div>
                <!--end card-body-->
            </div>
            <!--end card-->
        </div>
        <!-- end col-md-4-->
    </div>
```